# Add a summary block to a div | Squarespace

Tags: squarespace

I'm workin on a squarespace page (culturetoronto.com/art) and on this page I have a menu bar (look for the gradient) I made that I'd like to put a squarespace summary carousels into.

What is the code for a squarespace carousel that I can add to a place of my choosing?

I tried copying and pasting one of the carousels in the body into there and it sort of works but I have to update it everytime I add a new post in that category.

Thanks so much for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Everytime i load the page my browser crashes because of one of the script.

Why dont you try implementing something nice and easy like owl-slider.. Really nice effects and really easy to implement.

[Heres the link](http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/)